# How to properly select a div with this?

Tags: javascript, jquery, this

I have a list of products, each one displayed whithin a div like this :

```
<div data-productSheetId="n" class="productSheet"></div>
```

My current selector is the following :

```
var productSheet = $('[data-productSheetId="' + $(this).data('productSheetId') + '"]');
```

I'm pretty sure i'm doing it wrong, how could i select it properly ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You likely meant to

1. have an all lowercase attribute
2. use the data-attribute to select the productsheet by its id

like this

```
<div id="xxx" class="productSheet"></div>
<div id="yyy" class="productSheet"></div>
<div id="zzz" class="productSheet"></div>

<button class="btn" type="button" data-productsheetid="xxx">Select XXX</button>

$(function() {
  $(".btn").on("click",function() { 
    // get the id to access from the button's data attribute
    var id = $(this).data("productsheetid"); // for readability
    var productSheet = $("#"+id);
  });  
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `.filter()` method:

```
var productSheet = $("div.productSheet").filter(function() {
    return $(this).data("productsheetid") == "n";
});
```

**Update**:

Thanks to @mplungjan. The data attributes should be all lowercase. Now, when the attribute has hyphens, the camel-case equivalent can be used to read the data:

```
//<div data-productsheetid="n" class="productSheet"></div>
//use:
.data('productsheetid')

//<div data-product-sheet-id="n" class="productSheet"></div>
//use either:
.data('product-sheet-id')
//or:
.data('productSheetId')
```

Comment: I believe attributes need to be all lowercase

Comment: Good point. As long as the user understands that `productSheetId` is converted to `product-sheet-id` there shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: My tests do not confirm your findings. Can you check if I coded what you meant: https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/yf9jLy03/ ?

Comment: Thank you @mplungjan. The hyphen and camel-case are on the data-attribute itself, not the value. Please check the lines with comments in the JS [**HERE**](https://jsfiddle.net/njLjc5w6/2/). Please let me know if you have any further questions.

Answer (score 1):

Just lowercase your key:

```
productSheet = $('[data-productSheetId="' + $(this).data('productsheetid') + '"]');
```

The camelcase key you are using (productSheetId) is used for attributes like

```
 <div data-product-sheet-id="n" class="productSheet"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var x = 5;

var productSheet = $('div[data-productSheetId =' + x + ']');
```

This is going to do trick. Just change the variable `x` when selecting.